# When starting a web project, is it better to start with the client-side or the server-side?

Tags: web, client-side, server-side, methodology

I'm planning to start a web project soon. Which should be done first? Is it better to do the client-side scripting (HTML, CSS, JS, Design, etc) first, or is it better to create a very simple draft with barely any CSS with the server-side scripting (Ruby, PHP, Python, etc) then build the design and client-side on top of that?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the database models. I guess you want to store some data. Organize your data first. Then, if you use django (python), create a models.py.

Of course you can start with the front end first, too. But I would do it with a pencil and paper.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I follow.

1.Choose your tools first.

2.Create a solid architecture(which can endure specification changes).

3.Create dummy inputs(no fancy stuff,just simple input boxes and buttons to send your data to the server)

4.Start with your scripting(PHP,python,ruby).

5.Proceed with the entire Design process from scratch creating templates(HTML),Styling them(CSS) and making them interactive(JS).

6.Tightly integrate all aspects.